# Getting redirected URL in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, redirect, urllib

I want to get the address of a page after redirect. I have the following code

```
url = 'https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gcd'
print(urlopen(url).geturl())
```

But it doesn't work, it prints https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gcd, while it should print https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor.

So, what is the problem with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually no problem. The URL you get when opening `https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gcd` *is* exactly that URL. The only way for the URL to change would be a redirect, and if you look at the response from that URL, you can see that it returns just a 200 status code. So there is no redirect.

However, when you open the URL in the browser, the URL does get changed to `https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor`. How does this happen when there is no redirect?

This is actually a new MediaWiki feature that rewrites the URL in the browser using the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/History). It simply replaces the URL that is displayed in the browser—but without actually making a new request or being a true HTTP redirect.

It’s a functionality that only works in modern browsers with JavaScript enabled. Otherwise, you would stay on the `Gcd` URL which is also the behavior from older versions of MediaWiki.

You can learn more about this new MediaWiki feature in the [Phabricator task T37045](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T37045).

As for your “problem” with it, you should consider communicating with MediaWiki using the [MediaWiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) which will also tell you when a page is a redirect.